# Save and restore state of uinavigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a problem with the UINavigationController.

I have a application that have so many view controllers that I'm switching between using the navigation controllers push and pop functionality.

My requirement is like that : In my app when user is on the 5th screen and user click home button and again double click home button and delete or kill the app from multitasking bar and then user tap on app icon (open the app) app should start from where it leave or app should start form 5th screen.

I do the code in app delegate in applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationDidBecomeActive but it doesn't help me

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    self.viewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UINavigationController* navController = self.navigationController;
    int viewcountt = [navController.viewControllers count];

    NSLog(@"descbefor -- %@",[navController.viewControllers description]);
    NSLog(@"kountbefor -- %d",[navController.viewControllers count]);


    for (int cont=0; cont < viewcountt; cont++)
    {
        [self.viewArray addObject:[navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:cont]];

    }
}
```

i try to save self.viewArray but it cant be save. and retrive.

Is it possible to do like this or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar and created a class to save state of the different branches to `NSUserDefaults`.  When each scene loads, I call a class method to save the current scene for the branch name.

Here is the class:

Interface file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SceneController : NSObject

+(NSString *)getSceneNameWithBranchName:(NSString *)name;

+(void)saveSceneNameWithBranchName:(NSString *)name andSceneName:(NSString *)sceneName;

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "SceneController.h"

@implementation SceneController

+(NSString *)getSceneNameWithBranchName:(NSString *)name {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *sceneName = [prefs valueForKey:name];

    return sceneName;
}

+(void)saveSceneNameWithBranchName:(NSString *)name andSceneName:(NSString *)sceneName {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setValue:sceneName forKey:name];
    [prefs synchronize];
}

@end
```

This works well for me and will survive app restarts.